# I want to Retriew data from database through codeigniter but show this error

Tags: codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Mypage::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 51

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\models\user_model.php on line 11
```

Comment: Plz Somebody help me.....

Comment: Post some code too not just the error.

Comment: According to this $db is not defined in your model anywhere. Are you extending your database class in your model?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are not loading the database library.

Edit your `application/config/autoload.php`

Like,

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are getting this error because you have not loaded you database library. You need to load the database library in autoload, or in your model, the `$db object` is referencing the database library.

```
$this->load->library('database');  //in your model function do this
```

But you will have to repeat this for every function or do this in the constructor of the model the choice is yours, but the best option would be to load the database in the `autoload.php`:

```
 autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```